# How to declare a Spring bean autowire-candidate="false" when using annotations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I am using `@ComponentScan` and `@Component` to define my spring beans. What I would like is to declare one of these beans to be `autowire-candidate=false`.

This could be done with this attribute in xml. Isn't there the equivalent in annotations?

The reason I want this is because I have 2 implementations of the same interface and I don't want to use `@Qualifier`.

EDIT: Using @Primary is a valid work-around, but autowire-candidate seems to me like a useful feature with its own semantics.

Thanks

Comment: Annotate the preferred one with `@Primary`. No need to use a `@Qualifier` that way.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, that is actually one way I have found to overcome the problem, but I am just wondering how come there is no equivalent of autowire-candidate in annotations.

Comment: Looks like Spring refused `autowire-candidate=false` concept and it no longer supported. There is no analogue with annotations, so `@Primary` is only way as you noticed.

Comment: Sergey Bespalov, probably you should write it as answer, because seemed that it is the only truth.

Comment: @НиколайМитропольский, done with some additional suggestion.

Answer (score 9):

Looks like Spring refused `autowire-candidate=false` concept and it no longer supported. There is no analogue with annotations, so `@Primary` is the best work-around as you noticed.

Another way is to use custom `org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AutowireCandidateResolver`, which is used in `DefaultListableBeanFactory`, with logic that exclude undesirable beans from autowire candidates. In such case, the  technology will be similar to that used for `autowire-candidate=false` in `SimpleAutowireCandidateResolver`.

Answer (score 9):

Since Spring 5.1 , you can configure `autowire-candidate` in `@Bean` through  `autowireCandidate` attribute:

```java
@Bean(autowireCandidate = false)
public FooBean foo() {
      return newFooBean();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the bean accessor to tune it's visibiltiy.

see [Bean visibility](https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/creating-bean-definitions.html#bean-visibility)

```
@Configuration
public abstract class VisibilityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Bean publicBean() {
        Bean bean = new Bean();
        bean.setDependency(hiddenBean());
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    protected Bean hiddenBean() {
        return new Bean("protected bean");
    }
}
```

You can then `@Autowire` the `Bean` class and it will autowire the **`public`** bean (without complaining about multiple matching beans)

As a class' definition (unless embedded) does not allow **`private`** / **`protected`** accessor the work around would be to use an `@Configuration` class that would instantiate all the beans an publish the public beans while hiding the private/protected (instead of directly annotating the classes `@Component` \ `@Service`)

Also package-protected accessor may worth a try to hide `@Component` annotated classes. I don't know if that may work.

Comment: Are you sure the Bean Visibility is implemented in Spring?

Comment: @Whimusical yes, I created a class as defined in my answert and Autowired an attribute of type "Bean" in another spring component and spring injected the 'public' Bean.

Comment: I was thinking of https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/11829 and the fact that most documentation I see on the net regarding that feature is on Spring 1.0, but they must be outdated

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by using the `@Qualifier` annotations with name mentioned in the `@Component` annotations
Bean classes -

```
@Component("fooFormatter")
public class FooFormatter implements Formatter {
    public String format() {
        return "foo";
    }
}
@Component("barFormatter")
public class BarFormatter implements Formatter {
    public String format() {
        return "bar";
    }
}
```

Injecting bean in service class -

```
public class FooService {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("fooFormatter")
    private Formatter formatter;
}
```

For more details please refer - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire#disambiguation. Above example taken from this link.

Answer (score 0):

Use Object type to create the Bean you want to hide

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MyInterface publicBean() {
        return new MyInterfaceImpl1();
    }

    @Bean
    protected Object hiddenBean() {
       return new MyInterfaceImpl2();
    }
}
```

Then you can use a simple @Autowired to inject publicBean

```
@Component
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    MyInterface publicBean;

}
```

And even if you wanted to inject also hiddenBean in other place, then you could using @Qualifier

```
@Component
public class OtherComponent {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("hiddenBean")
    MyInterface hiddenBean;

}
```